# How do I take a clip of a larger video file?

Tags: video-editing

I want to extract a clip of a larger video file.

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[VirtualDub](http://www.free-codecs.com/download/VirtualDub.htm) is the best.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to script it, you could use ffmpeg.

To save a single frame:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mpg -an -ss 00:01:43 -t 00:00:01 -r 1 -s 320x240 video%d.jpg
```

where ss is the start time, t is the end time (relative after the start).  If you want to generate a frame every 5 seconds thoughout the entire video:

```
ffmpeg -i test.avi -r 0.2 -s 640x480 image%02d.jpg
```

where r is the frame rate .2 = 1/5 of the nominal 24 fps.

Comment: Nice, will have to try that tonight

Answer (score 1):

I just did this with [Avidemux](http://fixounet.free.fr/avidemux/) and found it quite easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

Quickest way (if in Windows) is to use Windows Movie Maker, it should allow you to edit pretty much any video that you can use in Windows Media Player and shrink, clip or anything.

Answer (score 0):

Well My favorite is [Video Cutter](http://www.prvsoft.com/video-cutter.html).

Two features which I love about is

1) Its very Easy

2) supports many video formats

More info [here](http://www.freevideocutter.com/)