# Batch movie frame extractor?

Tags: video, images, processing, extract

Can anyone suggest a windows applications that will extract x amount of frames from a list of movies that are imported into it. It needs to operate in batch mode. Image Grabber II .net would be perfect... but it wont work under Vista or Windows 7 (64bit) for me.... so Im looking for an alternative.

Comment: I agree with @John T - ffmpeg is the best batch approach.  Your question is similar to [this one][1].

  [1]: http://superuser.com/questions/47936/suggest-a-video-clipping-app/49343#49343

Answer (score 1):

For a GUI approach, there is [**Video to JPG Converter**](http://www.dvdvideosoft.com/guides/dvd/make-video-snapshots.htm):

[image]

For a command line approach, you can use [**FFmpeg**](http://ffmpeg.org):

```
ffmpeg -i file.avi -y -ss 5 -an -sameq -f image2 -r 1/5 filename%03d.jpg
```

this should create output files of frames every 5 seconds with a name like `filename0001.jpg`, `filename0002.jpg`, etc. You can find information on all available switches in the [**FFmpeg Documentation**](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-doc.html). To process multiple files, you can use `*.avi` as input for example.

Comment: Both ffmpeg and this appeach are MUCH slower than the Image Grabber 2 program approach. In it, it takes about 5 seconds per movie.... this takes about 2 minutes.

Comment: try running image grabber in XP compatibility mode?

Comment: no effect on the speed